# postgresql: creating a text to integer multiplication operator

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am looking to debug a Microsoft SQL query inside of Posgresql (long story short I prefer the error messages it returns) when I came across some SQL that was multiplying a substring select with an integer, now I could obviously cast each part using `::integer` however there are many substrings that need casting and many queries I wanted to run through so I decided that I might make my life easier by using an operator to address this with the use of the following function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.multiplytext2int(text,integer)
RETURNS integer AS
$$
SELECT CASE
        WHEN $1 ~ '^[0-9]+$'
        THEN $1::integer * $2
        ELSE 0::integer
    END
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

obviously the logic is not completely airtight but will suffice for the queries I will be running, so then I try to create the operator

```
CREATE OPERATOR * (
     LEFTARG = text
    ,RIGHTARG = integer
    ,FUNCTION = multiplytext2int
)
```

when I run this I get the following error

> WARNING:  operator attribute "function" not recognized ERROR: 
>   operator procedure must be specified
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: operator procedure must be specified SQL state: 42P13

what am I doing wrong here?

ultimately I am looking to be able to be able to type `SELECT '1'::text * 2::integer` without an operator does not exist error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's a function, the argument to use is `procedure`.

```
CREATE OPERATOR * (
     LEFTARG = text
    ,RIGHTARG = integer
    ,PROCEDURE = multiplytext2int
)
```

Comment: I just discovered my mistake I was looking through the wrong version of the documentation (postgresql 11) thank you very much for your answer.